# The QR scanner app is having some weird problem,

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-mlkit

using MLKIT I tried to make a scanner app but it crashes for some reason, 
  I don't understand the log plz help!! I am linking the main activity and
  error log. The app is not even starting, I think something is wrong with 
 the layout . will link layout as well. The app only has one activity and i am linking essentially the whole project .

Error:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.akatski.mlqrcscanner, PID: 22393
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.akatski.mlqrcscanner/com.akatski.mlqrcscanner.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2952)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3087)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1817)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6746)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.akatski.mlqrcscanner.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2932)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3087)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1817)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6746)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:495)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 22393 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Main activity:

```
package com.akatski.mlqrcscanner

import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVision
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.FirebaseVisionBarcode
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.barcode.FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImage
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.common.FirebaseVisionImageMetadata
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter
import com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionsReport
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.multi.MultiplePermissionsListener
import com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView
import com.otaliastudios.cameraview.frame.Frame
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.File
import java.lang.StringBuilder
import java.util.jar.Manifest
import kotlin.system.exitProcess

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    internal var isDetected = false
    lateinit var options:FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions
    lateinit var detector:FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetector



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        Dexter.withActivity(this@MainActivity)
            .withPermissions(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
            .withListener(object:MultiplePermissionsListener{
                override fun onPermissionsChecked(report: MultiplePermissionsReport?) {
                    setupCamera()
                }

                override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                    permissions: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?,
                    token: PermissionToken?
                ) {

                }


            }).check()




    }

    private fun setupCamera() {
        options=FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder()
            .setBarcodeFormats(FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE)
            .build()

        detector= FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options)
        btn_again.isEnabled = isDetected
        btn_again.setOnClickListener{
            isDetected=!isDetected
            btn_again.isEnabled=isDetected


        }

       cameraView.setLifecycleOwner(this)
        cameraView.addFrameProcessor { frame -> processImage(getVisionImageFromFrame(frame))}





        }

    private fun processImage(image: FirebaseVisionImage) {
if(!isDetected)
{
    detector.detectInImage(image)
        .addOnFailureListener{ exception -> Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,""+exception.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
        .addOnSuccessListener{firebaseVisionBarcodes ->
            processResult(firebaseVisionBarcodes)
        }
}



    }

    private fun processResult(firebaseVisionBarcodes: List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>) {
        if(firebaseVisionBarcodes.size>0)
        {

            isDetected=true
            btn_again.isEnabled = isDetected
            for(item in firebaseVisionBarcodes)
            {
                val value_type = item.valueType
                when(value_type)
                {
                FirebaseVisionBarcode.TYPE_TEXT ->{

                    createDialog(item.rawValue)
                }
                FirebaseVisionBarcode.TYPE_CONTACT_INFO ->{

                     val info = StringBuilder("Name:")
                         .append(item.contactInfo!!.name!!.formattedName)
                         .append("/n")
                         .append("Address: ")
                         .append(item.contactInfo!!.addresses[0].addressLines[0])
                         .append("/n")
                         .append("Email:")
                         .append(item.contactInfo!!.emails[0].address)
                         .toString()
                    createDialog(info)
                }
                    FirebaseVisionBarcode.TYPE_URL ->{
                        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(item.rawValue))
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }


                }
            }
        }


    }

    private fun createDialog(text: String?) {

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setMessage(text)
            .setPositiveButton("okay",{ DialogInterface, _-> DialogInterface.dismiss()  })

        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()




    }

    private fun getVisionImageFromFrame(frame: Frame): FirebaseVisionImage {
      val data =frame.data
       val metadata=FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.Builder()
           .setFormat(FirebaseVisionImageMetadata.IMAGE_FORMAT_NV21)
           .setHeight(frame.size.height)
           .setWidth(frame.size.width)
           //.setRotation(frame.rotation)
           .build()
        return FirebaseVisionImage.fromByteArray(data,metadata)



    }


}
```

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:id="@+id/info">
        <com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView
                android:id="@+id/cameraView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView>
        <view android:gravity="center"
              android:layout_width="200dp"
              android:layout_height="200dp"
              android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        >

        </view>


    </FrameLayout>


    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cinfo"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btn_again"
                android:text="SCAN AGAIN"
                android:enabled="false"

        />


    </LinearLayout>






</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can check out this tutorial also: https://www.natigbabayev.com/2019-07-13/building-qr-code-scanner-for-android-using-firebase-ml-kit-and-camerax

Answer (score 1):

```
  <View android:gravity="center"
              android:layout_width="200dp"
              android:layout_height="200dp"
              android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        >

        </View>
```

*Change your `<view>` tag to `<View>` that will fix you inflationException*